# Remove .git folder but keep changes

Tags: git, github

I have git repository inside git repository (don't know how that happened). How do I keep all changes made in the inner repository but delete it as a repository (but keep file structure).

file structure:
web/
--.git folder
-- other folders
-- public/
----angular project folders/
----.git folder

Comment: Technically, you *don't* have a repository inside a repository: Git does not allow that. Git replaces any attempt to cause that to happen with a *submodule* instead. Submodules are ... okay as far as they go, but many refer to them as *sob*-modules because of the pain and anguish they lead to, so removing the inner `.git` may well be what you want. It's hard to tell since only you can know what you want, in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the inner repository just by deleting that inner `.git` folder, with this action you will lose all git history / commits done in this inner repository but you will keep all the changes until this point in here, before doing this I will suggest to check if you have any hidden changes you will want to keep (`git stash list`), I'd understand you don't, but just in case.